# RIA domainservice/context call fails from Silverlight sometimes

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ria, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I have a very strange problem: I'm developing a Silverlight business application with RIA services.

I have some DomainServices on the server-side, and with one of them I'm having the problem, that *sometimes* calling one of the methods fails (on the SL client, I get "NotFound" exception, and the request doesn't event arrive to the server (I put a breakpoint into the constructor of the domainservice)!

What makes things strange even more:

- If the call fails from the SL client, then I start Fiddler2, then the second (or any consecutive) call is working properly! If I close fiddler, it becomes unstable again.
- If I rename the method which I would like to call (via refactor), call renamed method on the context at SL client side too, then everytime I make the call it is successful!

Here is my suspicios method:

```
[Invoke]
public void RegisterTrainingProgramCompletion(bool isCompleted, int result, string sportsManNote)
{
 //...
}
```

If I rename this method to "RegisterTpCompletion", then it works (unbelievable)!

The DomainService is marked with some attributes:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
[RequiresAuthentication()]
public class NextTrainingProgramDomainService : DomainService
```

I managed to somehow log the server-side, and got the following exception from the WCF stack:

There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&amp; requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

So for some unknown reason the clint (SL-app) does not flush properly the request? I'm starting to worry :(((

My callers (SL client) are authenticated with custom forms authentication.

I know you could say, leave it then as it is, but this drives me crazy, I want to know what's the problem, so I do not run into it again.

Thanks!

Bye,
Csabi

Comment: I just saw your post from long time ago, but am running into a simmilar error (once in a while no accessing correctly my RIA entities) perhaps you got some better understanding of what went wrong and would like to share. do you still beleive that URL lenght or naming was your problem? Thanks Csabi.

Comment: Ramnz: nothing helped but renaming the function. I posted this question in many places, like RIAs forum, and I got no proper answer back (not even 'ok, it's a bug sorry'.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is URL issue, mostly URL can only be few kbs long. Now I don't know the size but in RIA services, it uses URL to send your filter as querystring.

And names of your method are also big, it is reaching max limit of URL. When it is working even with big name your filter part may be empty but if you add more filters you will face errors.

Comment: Dear Akash,

Thanks for your reply, but I was thinking about this too, and renamed the method to "RegisterTrainingProgramCompletionXXX" and it worked like a charm (3 of 3 times)! Then when I renamed it back to "RegisterTrainingProgramCompletion" then it fails again.

This is totally insane!

I searched for string "RegisterTrainingProgramCompletion" in the whole solution and found no harmful relevant code.

Comment: Ok I think it's the Completion postfix that may be the problem. For example it may be assuming method name + Completion as some sort of checkpoint in it's own internal logic. I have seen WCF failing when we use string as parameter and send custom XML that purposely conflicts names used in WPF and we get 400 error as request was not understood.

Comment: Hihi :) I renamed it to "RegisterTrainingProgramCompletio" (no 'n' at the end) and it works. Then I thought maybe <EntitiyName>Completion causes the problem, so I renamed it to RegisterTrainingProgramHistoryCompletion (TPH is also an entitiy, same as TP), and it worked like a charm :) I renamed it back to RegisterTrainingProgramCompletion and fails again :)

Can't believe.